# How to order by two different things at once in a query in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am having a little problem. I am trying to get the latest 12 post by a custom meta field. Out of those 12 posts, I want to order them by post date. So first I pull 12 posts out using a custom meta field and ordering them to find the latest through the meta field. Once I have them, then I want to re-order them with latest post.

Here is my current code, I don't know how I can put two order-bys in one query...

```
$recentEpisodes12 = new WP_Query(array(
    'posts_per_page' => 12,
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'meta_key' => 'air_date',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'air_date',
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'already_aired',
            'value' => 'yes',
            'compare' => '='
        )
    ),

));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[According to the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters), you simply need to separate them by a space:

> **Multiple 'orderby' values**
>
> Display pages ordered by 'title' and 'menu_order'. (title is
>   dominant):
>
> ```
> $query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'page', 'orderby' => 'title menu_order', 'order' => 'ASC' ) );
> ```

In your case, that would look like:

```
'orderby' => 'meta_value_num date'
```

**EDIT:** Okay, it seems like you're trying to do something a bit more complex here. This is how I interpret it, correct my if I'm wrong:

1. Order by `air_date` (in descending order, newest first).
2. Keep only the 12 newest items *according to* `air_date`.
3. Order the resulting 12 items by `date`.

What `orderby` does is basically:

1. Order by `air_date`.
2. If any items have *identical* `air_date` values, order those by `date`.
3. Keep only the top 12 items.

The difference is that *you only want to distinguish* by `air_date`, whereas the normal usage of `orderby` uses both criteria to determine which items end up in the result.

I don't know an easy way to solve this, though. However, since you only want to change the *display order* of the resulting items, you could just sort those yourself. You can use `get_posts` instead of `WP_Query` and sort the results array using PHP's [`usort`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)

```
$posts = get_posts(...);
usort($posts, '__sort_by_date_desc');

function __sort_by_date_desc($a, $b) {
    // Make timestamps from MySQL datetime values
    $a_date = mysql2date('U', $a->post_date);
    $b_date = mysql2date('U', $b->post_date);
    // Descending order, swap these for ascending
    return $b_date - $a_date;
}
```

Comment: You seem to have the right answer but it is giving me unexpected results. And not close to what I am trying to accomplish x.x
`'orderby' => 'date meta_value_num',` ... Even tried to change the order since the one that comes first takes precedence.

Comment: Yeah, that's basically what I want to do. Will I need to use get_posts for the usort function in php? Also, how would I go about comparing the post dates once I get the 12 items from air_date. I am not too great with PHP.

Comment: @user27899 I updated my answer with a simple sort callback. I prefer `get_posts` when I don't want to mess with the "main loop". You could do the same with `query_posts`, then you have to sort `$wp_query->posts` immediately after retrieving your posts.

Comment: Excellent! Worked perfectly!

Answer (score 7):

In WordPress 4.2 and up, ordering by one or more custom fields was made much easier. See this link for examples: https://make.wordpress.org/core/2015/03/30/query-improvements-in-wp-4-2-orderby-and-meta_query/

You can even order one column ASC and another DESC by passing an array to orderby now:

```
'orderby' => array(
    'city_clause' => 'ASC',
    'state_clause' => 'DESC',
),
```

Answer (score 0):

So if you want to order them by post date, why do you need a meta field for that? Once you get the 12 latest posts by meta value, is the `air_date` somehow different from the post date?

Worth noting: `posts_per_page` doesn't limit the total number of returns. It just tells WordPress when to split into a new page.

Something like this should work based on what you described in your original post.

```
// Post Criteria
$post_criteria = array(
    'posts_per_page'  => 12, // Don't paginate until after 12 posts
    'orderby'         => 'post_date', // Order by post date
    'order'           => 'DESC', // Order them reverse chronologically (ie. get the newest first)
    'meta_key'        => 'air_date', // Only get posts with this meta key
    'meta_value'      => 'meta_value_num', // And this meta value (only needed if you have multiple possible values for the meta key and just want one)
    'post_type'       => 'post', // Only get posts
    'post_status'     => 'publish'); // Only get posts that are published (ie. no drafts, etc.)

// Get posts matching criteria
$posts = get_posts( $post_criteria );

// Discard posts after the 12th one
$posts = array_slice($posts, 0, 12);

// If you wanted to reverse them to display
// chronologically, uncomment this variable.
# $posts = array_reverse($posts);

// For each post
foreach ($posts as $post) {

    // Basic variables
    // See a full list here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post#Return
    $id = $post->ID;
    $title = $post->post_title;
    $url = get_permalink($id);
    $content = $post->post_content;

    // Do stuff with the posts here.

}
```

Comment: Get the 12 posts sorted by meta_value_num... air date is much different than post date. Once I get the 12 posts by meta_value_num then I sort them by post date.